# NServiceBus Loading All Assemblies Regardless of Setting

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to run an NServiceBus solution containing several endpoint configs in one directory. I am executing the host.exe with (among other things) /endpointConfigurationType:"class, assembly".

The host correctly isolates itself to using only the one endpoint config, but then it appears to scan the directory anyway, loading and leveraging any NSB interfaces found in other DLLs that are used by the other services. For example, the IWantToRunAtStartup implementations in other endpoint DLLs are being executed even though I only expect NSB to care about interfaces found in /endpointConfigurationType.

What all steps are required to deploy an NSB solution to a flat folder structure, such that NSB will only concern itself with the endpoint it is told to execute?

Answer (score 2):

See the "File Scanning" section of this page:

http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856698-the-nservicebus-host

Comment: Thanks Udi. I will try this on Monday when I'm in the office. I've read this page a million times over, but I suppose the implications of that information wasn't obvious until you pointed me there.

Comment: I'm getting a NullRef exception inside NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() when using Configure.With(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) . Ideas? I only need to include assemblies with NSB interfaces I want scanned, right? In this case, I only want the current endpoint assembly.

Comment: at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start()
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start()
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Main>b__3(WindowsHost service)
   at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj)
   at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<set_StartAction>b__1(TService service)
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc)
   at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter)
...

Comment: Below is the Configure code: Configure
                .With(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
                .UnicastBus()
                .MessageFailureManager()
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                .XmlSerializer()
                .FileShareDataBus(busPath)
                .MsmqTransport()
                .ForInstallationOn<Windows>()
                    .Install();

Comment: @MartinBliss you need to include all of your assemblies that have things like message handlers in them as well as the NServiceBus assemblies.

Comment: The problem persists. I have a solution with many endpoints all building to the same folder. I have the project set to exec the NSB host exe, passing in the correct /endpointConfigurationType flag. In that respective endpoint config, I am passing in all of executing assembly's referenced assemblies using the With() method. With this config, I am getting an exception because NSB is calling IWantToRunAtStartup.Run() on an implementation that is in the same build folder but NOT in the referenced assemblies, suggesting NSB is still scanning the directory despite the NSB host flag and endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Configure.With(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                 .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
                 .FileShareDataBus(BasePath)
                 .UnicastBus()
                 .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                 .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                 .XmlSerializer()
                 .MsmqTransport();
```

Regarding the installation, just make sure you run /install for each /endpointConfigurationType, see http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856698#installation

Comment: See the Comments section under Udi's answer for problems I'm having with this approach.

Comment: @MartinBliss, Did you noticed I slightly changed the order of the fluent API calls?

Comment: I get a TopShelf exception. Per Udi, you have to pass in the NSB assemblies (not just the executing assembly.)

Comment: Actually that is not entirely right, we have changed that code so that the NServiceBus assemblies are always included regardless, see https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/config/NServiceBus.Config/Configure.cs#L227, the change was actually done by me, hence the reason I know it, https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/ca33bc08086d12c0e92f9c5d95e1e196365f7647.  This change went out as part of v3.0.4

Comment: Also, you could be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/822) that is fixed in v4 ?

Comment: I will double check the version we're using tomorrow morning. It is not the issue you linked, though I ran into this bug awhile ago. The NSB solution I inherited has over 20 services so I'm trying to get one of the services to work correctly in a console environment before configuring the services. As such, I am passing everything to the host directly when exec'ing from the command line.